# How to generate predefined values for xaml property with typeconverter

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, intellisense

If I have a control and I start typing a foreground property for it, it offers me a list of Colors, seemingly from the `Colors` class.
edit: I think it's actually the KnownColor enum, which is internal.

How is this achieved?

I have an attached property which is of type `MyClass`. I have a static class with some pre-cooked instances of `MyClass`. I want to achieve the same behavior described above.

I know I can use a type converter and convert from the string to an instance, but this seems a little more advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a Type converter.  The Xaml parser has built-in special handling of known types such as `Brush` and `Color`.

Comment: So there's no way to extend this special handling to my own stuff the way you can in WPF (with the TypeConverter's GetStandardValues method)?

Comment: @ArmedMonkey: No, Silverlight does not have that method or an alternative.